# How to manipulate objects after adding them to a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, object

This is a very elemental question about object-orientated programming- so sorry in advance if this is obvious.

I have a view and add several objects to this view (as subviews). I do this programatically. Every object get's an individual ID so that I can later tell objects apart (in this case it is the int position). This is my code:

```
    for (int i=0; i < [directories count]; i++) {

    NSLog(@"%i", i);

    Notebook *aBook = [[Notebook alloc] initWithName:aName withPosition:i];
    [self.view addSubview:aBook];
    [aBook release];
    [aName release];

}
```

After this, a have a view with several objects attached to it. My question is how I can get to these objects now. What if I wanted to find out the name or any other variable saved in this object? E.g. how would I get the nameOfBook if I knew what the stackPosition is? Here is the header of my object notebook:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Notebook : UIView

{
    NSString *nameOfBook;
    int stackPosition;
    int bookWidth;
    int bookHeight;
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nameOfBook;
@property int stackPosition;
@property int bookWidth, bookHeight, xPosition, yPosition;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name withPosition:(int)position;
-(void)putOnScreen;

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array or dictionary of your Notebook objects and add each one into there. Then you can reference them later on by getting the array / dictionary object.

So create instance var for your array....

```
NSMutableArray *myBooks;
```

And then add your objects into the array in your loop....

```
[myBooks addObject:aBook];
```

And when you want to retrieve it later (using 0 based index)....

```
Notebook *theBook = [myBooks objectAtindex:myIndexNumberHere];
```

Comment: Oh - and remember to initialise your array in your init method, and dealloc it too.

Comment: Thanks, but then I still have the same problem (I think). Suppose I put all my noteBooks in myBooks. I would still need to add them as subviews to my view (so that I actually have something on the screen). So they would now be found in the array and as subviews of my view. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The array would store a reference to the object that's in your view - so you can still add them to your view.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your view controller.

```
-(UIView*)getNotevookForName:(NSString*)name{
    for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews)
        if ([v isKindOfClass:Notebook.class] && [[(Notebook*)v nameOfBook] isEqualToString:name])
            return v;
    return nil;

}
```

This approach won't too efficient if you have a lot of `Notebook` views

Answer (score 1):

Since you add them as a subview, they are probably descendants of `UIView`. Why not use `tag` property like so:

```
int kBookTagIndex = 10;
for (int i=0; i < [directories count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%i", i);
    Notebook *aBook = [[Notebook alloc] initWithName:aName withPosition:i];
    [aBook setTag:i+kBookTagIndex];
    [self.view addSubview:aBook];
    [aBook release];
    [aName release];
```

}

and retrieve it later on:

```
int stackIndex = 4;
Notebook *aBook = [self.view viewForTag:stackIndex+kBookTagIndex];
```